# Google AdSense code not executed in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I put the AdSense script in my asp.net web site code.
I see that the script executed and I also receive from Google the relevant code.
But What I receive I see it in my web site as text and not as executable code.
I see that with Firebug.
Additionally I have to say that this script stays behind a DIV and that div is behind of a ContentHolder and that Holder is behind another DIV.
Can someone tell me why that happen? And How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The all issue is solved if we place the:

```
<%= IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("../pages/google.htm"))%>
```

Then we pass an htm page into an asp.net PlaceHolder and all it's fine.